# Creating a blank (" ") value in SQL using LEFT JOIN

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am running a LEFT JOIN between two tables according to an ON logic. I want to create an empty (" ") value if the ON logic is null. Can SQL do this?

Sample code below:

```
SELECT LeftTable.X, RightTable.*
FROM LeftTable 
LEFT JOIN RightTable ON LeftTable.X >= RightTable.Y 
                    AND LeftTable.X <= RightTable.Z
```

Use case example:

Your answer address the question posted, but i think not 'exactly' what I am trying to generate in the report.

To elaborate, lets give LeftTable = TimeReference which looks like. Please note the main hurdle I am facing is when the RightTable (named 'Schedule') lacks hours between a range of time. The SQL code doesn't have any command to know where to make a blank thus the final report skips this time block...

```
7:00:00 AM
7:30:00 AM
8:00:00 AM
8:30:00 AM
9:00:00 AM
9:30:00 AM
10:00:00 AM
10:30:00 AM
11:00:00 AM
11:30:00 AM
12:00:00 PM
12:30:00 PM
-etc.
```

While RightTable = Schedule:

```
Group1  Group2  Start   End Event
2      6    8AM      9PM    math
1      5    9AM     10PM    geography
1      5    830AM   9AM     history
1      6    700PM   10PM    history
2      6    2PM     5PM     education
2      6    1:30PM  2PM     math
2      5    9AM     10AM    math
```

Basically, I am trying to merge these 2 tables to look like this where time is standardized by 1 hour increments across all group combinations.

```
Group1  Group2 6    Start   Activity    
1       6   7AM     Math
1       6   8AM     Math
1       6   9AM     
1       6   10AM    geography
1       6   11AM    history
1       6   12PM    Math
...

1       5   7AM     geography
1       5   8AM     
1       5   9AM     
1       5   10AM    
1       5   11AM    history
1       5   12PM    geography
...


(and so on for '2' of group1 and '6' & '5' of group2
```

Comment: for which field? Have come across the COALESCE function? You didn't mention which DBMS you're using but most will have that, and/or ISNULL or something equivalent.

Comment: Using MS Access, which uses the JET engine.

For all fields in the RightTable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will work on most databases (you didn’t specify which database you are using):

```
SELECT
    LeftTable.X,
    COALESCE(RightTable.col1, ' ') as col1,
    COALESCE(RightTable.col2, ' ') as col2,
    ... etc for all other columns in RightTable
FROM LeftTable
LEFT JOIN RightTable ON LeftTable.X >= RightTable.Y
    AND LeftTable.X <= RightTable.Z
```

Unfortunately, you have to code a `COALESCE` individually for every column.

By the way, you ask for “empty”, but your example is a single space character, not a blank (zero chars). To get truly empty values, you would code:

```
COALESCE(RightTable.col1, '') as col1 —- blank rather than space
```

——-

Apparently, the `Nz()` function of MS Access will work instead of `coalesce()` although it only takes two parameters, but that’s enough here.

——-

To further enhance this query to produce output for every hour, even if there’s no scheduled events, you have to create and use an “hours” table:

```
create table hours (hour varchar(4));
insert into hours values ('7AM');
—- etc for all hours you want data for
```

Then left join from that. I don’t know your scheme, so I can only guess, but it will look something like:

```
SELECT
    hour,
    COALESCE(RightTable.col1, ' ') as col1,
    COALESCE(RightTable.col2, ' ') as col2,
    ... etc for all other columns in RightTable
FROM Hours
JOIN LeftTable on hour = LeftTable.X
LEFT JOIN RightTable ON LeftTable.X >= RightTable.Y
    AND LeftTable.X <= RightTable.Z
```

Comment: I am using MS Access, although I realize I should be using mySQL. Beginner's mistake. Much thanks for your input.    Think I made the problem easier than it is. Would this work if I need to duplicate LeftTable.X via grouping? As an example, LeftTable.X is Time.hours (from 9 to 9PM in 1 hour increments) while RightTable.Z and RightTable.Y is start and time. There is also RIghtTable.W that separates the data to two teams. How would I capture this?

Comment: See edit at the end of my answer. And yes, this will work with grouping.

Comment: I tried both COALESCE and Nv and get an "undefined function" ¯\_(ツ)_/¯      Am I suppose to tweak the SQL code around to account for the grouping?

Comment: Fixed: It is the 'Nz' function not Nv. Please fixed that in the answers! Much thanks again =)

Comment: Oops typo! Sorry about that. Good job finding the correct name. I corrected my answer.

Comment: Your answer address the question posted, but i think not 'exactly' what I am trying to generate in the report. I updated the question with a sample of the dataset I am working with to better explain my issue. I been toying with this in and out all Saturday. Still can't figure out.

Comment: @Z.K.L see addition to my answer

Comment: Thanks. If I wanted the standardized time to follow 30 minute increments, can I just use the 'TimeReference' (i.e. LeftTable) instead of hour? Following your code, I get a syntax error in FROM clause

Comment: If you wanted 30 minute increments, you should put all of them in the “hours” table, which you can rename to something else more appropriate. The query I gave you is a basic example of how to use it given you haven’t provided your schema. I assume the syntax error is because you coded “hours” instead of “hour”, but nevertheless this chat/discussion via comment has gone on too long. If you can’t work it out, please have a go at writing a new query and ask a new question about it, and include your schema and sample data in it.